# 3D Plots in Lists

Tags: plotting

In Mathematica 12.2, putting a 3D plot into a list can change the location of the labeled axes. Using the example in ListPlot3D documentation, the location of one of the labeled axes of

```
ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, 
 Mesh -> All]
```

is different than the location of the same axis of

```
{ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, 
 Mesh -> All]}
```

Any suggestions as to how to make the list version exactly the same as the unlisted version?

Answer (score 6):

Be explicit about `AxesEdge`. If you use `Automatic`, it uses a different axes placement settings when enclosed inside a list. I don't know the reason for it.

```
p1 = ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 
    4}}
  , AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}
  , Mesh -> All
  ]

{
 p1
 }
```